# Why does postgres say cur does not exist when DECLARE in my code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to fetch this query in batches at it contains calculated values before I insert it into another table. So I declare it to fetch in batches.

It seems there might be an issue with cursor naming conventions in my PostgreSQL environment. I tried using it in double quote and it didn't work too.

When I run the code I got the error message

ERROR:  type "cur" does not exist on OPEN cur;

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
    BatchSize INT := 1000;
    RowCount INT := 0;
    Done BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    -- Declare a cursor for your SELECT statement
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            td.date,
            so.SoilId,
            cr.CropId,
        -- Add more more
        FROM
            Time td
        LEFT JOIN
            SoilDimension so ON DATE(so.timestamp) = td.date
        LEFT JOIN
            CropDimension cr ON DATE(cr.timestamp) = td.date
        LEFT JOIN
            SensorDimension se ON DATE(se.timestamp) = td.date
        LEFT JOIN
            IrrigationDimension ir ON DATE(ir.timestamp) = td.date
        LEFT JOIN
            WeatherDimension we ON DATE(we.timestamp) = td.date;

    -- Declare variables to hold row values
    DECLARE
        date_col DATE;
        SoilId_col INT;
        CropId_col INT;
        -- Add more variables for other columns as needed

    -- Open the cursor
    OPEN cur;

    -- Loop to fetch and insert data in batches
    LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO
            date_col,
            SoilId_col,
            CropId_col;
            -- Fetch other column values as needed

        -- Check if any rows were fetched, and break the loop if none were fetched
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            Done := TRUE;
            EXIT;
        END IF;

        -- Insert the fetched row into YourTargetTable
        INSERT INTO YourTargetTable (
            date,
            SoilId,
            CropId,
            -- Add other columns here
        ) VALUES (
            date_col,
            SoilId_col,
            CropId_col,
            -- Add other values here
        );

        -- Increment the row count
        RowCount := RowCount + 1;

        -- Add a delay if necessary to avoid overwhelming the system
        -- PERFORM pg_sleep(1); -- Uncomment this line and adjust the delay as needed

        -- Exit the loop if the desired batch size is reached
        IF RowCount >= BatchSize THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Close the cursor
    CLOSE cur;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing SQL command `DECLARE` and plpgsql command `OPEN`. It doesn't work. You should to use only plpgsql syntax. The cursor's declaration should be before `BEGIN`.

```
DECLARE
    curs1 refcursor;
    curs2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM tenk1;
    curs3 CURSOR (key integer) FOR SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 = key;
BEGIN
  OPEN curs2;
  ...
```

It is little bit messy, because inside [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) we can work with SQL commands, and SQL supports cursors, but PL/pgSQL supports cursors little bit different way and uses own implementation. SQL cursors and PL/pgSQL cursors are interface over some API inside Postgres, but these interfaces cannot to cooperate. So inside PL/pgSQL use **only** PL/pgSQL cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Plpgsql is a block structured language consisting of 3 sections:

- Declaration (declare),
- Execution (begin ... end;)
- and Exception handler (exception)

With only Execution section required. The Declaration sections contains local variable declarations *including cursors*. Further blocks are nest-able with `declare` or `begin` starting a new block. Anything declared within an inner block is not visible in an outer block.Your structure contains nested blocks. It can/should(?) be reduced to a single block.  So:

```
do $$ 
declare 
   -- declare local control variables
    batchsize int := 1000;
    rowcount int := 0;
    done boolean := false;

    -- declare a cursor for select statement
    cur cursor for
        select
            td.date,
            so.soilid,
            cr.cropid,
        -- add more more
        from
            time td
        left join
            soildimension so on date(so.timestamp) = td.date
        left join
            cropdimension cr on date(cr.timestamp) = td.date
        left join
            sensordimension se on date(se.timestamp) = td.date
        left join
            irrigationdimension ir on date(ir.timestamp) = td.date
        left join
            weatherdimension we on date(we.timestamp) = td.date;
        
    -- declare variables to hold row values
        date_col date;
        soilid_col int;
        cropid_col int;
begin

    -- open the cursor
    open cur;

    -- loop to fetch and insert data in batches
    loop
        fetch cur into
            date_col,
            soilid_col,
            cropid_col;
            -- fetch other column values as needed

        -- check if any rows were fetched, and break the loop if none were fetched
        if not found then
            done := true;
            exit;
        end if;

        -- insert the fetched row into yourtargettable
        insert into yourtargettable (
            date,
            soilid,
            cropid,
            -- add other columns here
        ) values (
            date_col,
            soilid_col,
            cropid_col,
            -- add other values here
        );

        -- increment the row count
        rowcount := rowcount + 1;

        -- add a delay if necessary to avoid overwhelming the system
        -- perform pg_sleep(1); -- uncomment this line and adjust the delay as needed

        -- exit the loop if the desired batch size is reached
        if rowcount >= batchsize then
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;

    -- close the cursor
    close cur;
end $$;
```

FYI, this entire block can be reduced to a single SQL statement as:

```
insert into yourtargettable (
            date,
            soilid,
            cropid,
            -- add other columns here
            ) 
    select
        td.date,
        so.soilid,
        cr.cropid,
        -- add more more
      from time td
      left join soildimension       so on date(so.timestamp) = td.date
      left join cropdimension       cr on date(cr.timestamp) = td.date
      left join sensordimension     se on date(se.timestamp) = td.date
      left join irrigationdimension ir on date(ir.timestamp) = td.date
      left join weatherdimension    we on date(we.timestamp) = td.date
      limit 1000;
```

**Issue** Your `select ...` statement does not have an `order by` clause which makes the statement *nondeterministic*. If you run it multiple times you will get different results. This is so for both the `do` block and the single statement. 

**Note:** Not tested no test data supplied.